# как создать меню справа в шапке сайта

Tags: html5, css3

Как создать меню справа в шапке сайта, чтобы оно не выезжало за содержимое сайта?

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body div {
    outline: 1px solid #000000;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
    
.container {
   width: 1200px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   position: absolute; 
}
    
#header {
    height: 600px;
    background:url(img/header.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
    
ul {
    text-align: center;
}
    
ul li {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
    
.float {
    float: right;
}
    
clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="float">
                            <li>11</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>11</li>
                            <li>11</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="topNav"></div>
            <div id="content"> 
                <p>
                    If you're involved in an internet marketing business, thenyou've probably already come face-to-face with your #1enemy - "Time Wasting".
                </p>
            </div> 
            <div id="leftNav"></div>    
            <div id="rightNav"></div> 
            <div class="clear"></div>            
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Это вопрос или утверждение?.

Comment: Добавьте пример того, что пытались сделать и, что хотите получить

Comment: @РашенБеар добавил

Comment: Каша в HTML, дивы не лежат друг в друге, меню не должно выходить за котент или что то другое?  У вас content лежит не в контейнере.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov когда начинаешь двигать окно браузера то меню просто выходит за рамки сайта это видно по бордеру в 1пикс

Comment: Ну так у вас div 100% + 1px outline

Comment: @RuslanSemenov убирая outline ничего не меняется как меню выходило за рамки содержимого сайта так оно и выходит

Comment: Я не проверял ваш код полностью, т.к. в нем много лишнего и трудно вообще понять что и для чего. Ниже кинул отредактированный, в нем все работает, ширину задавайте как вам удобно.

Comment: Нифига не понял.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример если понимаете flexBox

```css
 .site{
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #3F3F3F;
  min-height: 100vh;
 }

 nav{
  width: 100%;
 }

 .menu{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: pink;
  list-style: none;
 }
 .menu li{
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 article{
  padding: 0 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="site">
<nav>
 <ul class='menu'>
  <li>пункт 1</li>
  <li>пункт 2</li>
  <li>пункт 3</li>
  <li>пункт 4</li>
  <li>пункт 5</li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<article>
 Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Составитель пустился свое не от всех, власти продолжил использовало вопроса запятой родного предупредила журчит заголовок? Даль всеми она путь продолжил но.
</article>

</div>
```

Вот ваш код без flex, немного почистил

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

#header {
  background: url(img/header.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: yellow;
}

ul {
  text-align: right;
}

ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="header">
    <nav>
      <ul class="float">
        <li>11</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>11</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>
      If you're involved in an internet marketing business, thenyou've probably already come face-to-face with your #1enemy - "Time Wasting".
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: на сколько я знаю flexbox многие браузеры не поддерживают

Comment: Все, но нужно прогнать код префиксами, сейчас куча авто вариантов сделать это. А вот и поддержка http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Semenov не совсем ещё разбираюсь поэтому для меня это далеко пока

Comment: https://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/ вот сайт который изменит для вас css в универсальный формат.

Comment: Semenov спасибо

Comment: Добавил ваш код, и немного поправил, без flex

Comment: такой вопрос как работать с сайтом я должен взять свой код вставить флексбокс в нужное мне место и он даст мне уже рабочий код так получается? и что такое миксины в краце можете сказать

Comment: Нет flexbox это гибкий метод позиционирования с удобной адаптивностью. А миксины где вы уже прочитали? ) миксины это уже готовые куски кода которые программы вставляют за вас экономя время. Но я писал Вам за префиксы, префиксы это адаптация css свойств под различные браузеры для их поддержки.

Comment: Теперь стало немного понятней спасибо

Comment: мне одного не понят. почему когда я контейнер переношу  в хедер то меню опять съезжает...перенёс потому что мне нужны отступы на сайте по бокам

Comment: спасибо большое я понял как сделать просто нужно в медиа прописать max-width огромное человеческое спасибо наконец то решил проблему)

Comment: Не за что, почитайте flexbox они сейчас достаточно модные на них перешли и многие CMS и разработчики, пока гриды не раскручены.